# Why is my ProgressDialog listening on ANY KEY (touch) instead of backbutton to dismiss?

Tags: android, dialog, progress, back-button

i have a ProgressDialog implemented like this:

```
// show progress dialog while date is loading
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(XYActivity.this, getResources().getString(R.string.progress_dialog_please_wait), getResources().getString(R.string.progress_dialog_loading), true);
        progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                cancel(true);
                Log.w(LOGTAG, "loading cancelled via back button");
            }

        });
        progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
```

This ProgressDialog is implemented inside an AsyncTask (PreExecute), so the cancel(true) method stops the AsyncTask. This all works fine.

The **problem** is, that i can **cancel** the ProgressDialog **with any random touch** on my screen. I wanna to dismiss the dialog only by pressing the backbutton. Please help me! Thank you guys.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Title", "Loading...", true, true, new OnCancelListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
            cancel(true);
        }
    });
    progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
}
```

The `setCanceledOnTouchOutside` suggested by GedankenNebel is pretty clean.

Answer (score 1):

try below instruction

not sure about the whole cancel button...i've heard reports of the onCancel() method not firing properly. my solution just consists of making a normal button on the dialog with a call to return whenever the button is pressed.

```
private void createCancelProgressDialog(String title, String message, String buttonText)
{
    cancelDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    cancelDialog.setTitle(title);
    cancelDialog.setMessage(message);
    cancelDialog.setButton(buttonText, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
        {
            // Use either finish() or return() to either close the activity or just the dialog
            cancelDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    cancelDialog.show();
}
```

then just use a simple call method from elsewhere in your activity

```
createCancelProgressDialog("Loading", "Please wait while activity is loading", "Cancel");
```

rather simple solution, but it does the trick ;) also just to note that cancelDialog is an activity wipe variable, if you dont need to call it from elsewhere, then you should be able to get away with just limiting the scope of the variable to that method.

Comment: thanks, after adding `cancelDialog.setCancelable(false);`to your code this worked for me, but i found an easier solution see my below

Comment: I found a solution with the `progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);` :)))